# Set CODEOWNERS on files but not directories?

Tags: github

I have the following structure:

```
.github/ 
        CODEOWNERS
A/
         files
B/
         files
example.py
example2.py
```

I want code owners to have a specific owners on all files in the main directory.
I can do:

```
example.py   @owner
example2.py  @owner
```

But that means list them manually which is something I dont want to do as it doesnt offer protection against adding new files!

So my question is: How can I say all files in main directory but not folders?

Answer (score 1):

The CODEOWNERS docs have an [example file](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#example-of-a-codeowners-file), with this relevant bit:

```
# The `docs/*` pattern will match files like
# `docs/getting-started.md` but not further nested files like
# `docs/build-app/troubleshooting.md`.
docs/*  docs@example.com
```

So, to assign the root directory, but not its subdirectories, you could do

```
/* @owner
```